# javascript: add nested attribute in object

Tags: javascript

Wit this example object:

```
obj = {
    id: '123',
    attr: 'something'
}
```

Now I want to add the attribute `link` in the attribute `data`. Sometimes `data` is already existing, but in this example `data` doesn't exist.

So if I do

```
obj.data.link = 'www.website.com';
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'link' of undefined`.

Result should be:

```
obj = {
    id: '123',
    attr: 'something',
    data: {
        link: 'www.website.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: or just `obj.data = { link: 'www.website.com' }` ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the `data` object first:

```
obj.data = {};
obj.data.link = 'www.website.com';
```

or you can do it all at once:

```
obj.data = {
    link: 'www.website.com'
};
```

if `data` may or may not already by there, there's a handy shortcut that will use the existing one if it's there or create a new one if not:

```
obj.data = obj.data || {};
obj.data.link = 'www.website.com';
```

That uses the [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

Comment: `curiously powerful` - nice phrase - though, that page neglects the almost equally intriguing `&&` and what you can do with a combination of `&&` and `||`

Comment: @JaromandaX: I thought it did mention it, but I just checked and you're right! May need to revise it a bit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the data property. You can do something like this:

```
var obj = {
    id: '123',
    attr: 'something'
};

obj.data = {};
obj.data.link = 'www.website.com';
```

In the case for the property existing you can check before assigning link.

```
if (!obj.data) {
    obj.data = {};
}
```

And as stated in another answer you can use the or operator which I've heard is 'curiously powerful' =]

```
obj.data = obj.data || {};
```

That basically means if this value ( obj.data ) exists use it and if it doesn't use the right operand ( {} ). This works because of short circuit evaluation.

Comment: Missed that in question. Updated answer. Sorry! Thanks for heads up. =]

Comment: go `curiously powerful ™`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript From 1.8.5 you can use the following method:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "data", {
    value: {'link' : 'www.website.com'},
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Good luck :)